# How to combine function with other codes in one .m fine (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, function

```
clear all;
close all
clc

e = .25;
%fun = @find_root;
z = fzero(fun,1)
yy = z+.5^2*z/e-z^3/e

%=================================

function y = find_root(x)
    y1 = x+0.5^2*x/e-x^3/e;
    y = -e*x + e*y1 +.5^2*y1-y1^3 
end
```

It can work if I separate two parts in different .m file of the above code. However, when I 
combine them together, Matlab shows:

> Error: File: find_root.m Line: 11 Column: 14
>   Function with duplicate name "find_root" cannot be defined.

Since I want to set e from 0 to 1 in for loop and I cannot add parameter in the following way

```
z = fzero(fun(x,e),1)
```

that is why I have to combine both parts in ONE .m file.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so there is a few things wrong here. Firstly with your error:

> Error: File: find_root.m Line: 11 Column: 14 Function with duplicate name "find_root" cannot be defined.

This is caused when you give your file the same name as a function contained in the script. I suggest you change it to something else (e.g. `calc_yy.m`). Other than that you should define your function as a function handle with your desired input (`fun = @(x)find_root(x,e);` is a function handle with input `x`). Something else to watch out for is including `e` as a parameter for your function. If you do not include `e` as a function parameter in the definition `function y = find_root(x,e)` and the function handle `fun = @(x)find_root(x,e);`, then the `e` you defined earlier will be out of scope within the function. The following code worked just fine for me (saved as `test.m`):

```
%% Script
clear all
close all
clc

e = .25;
fun = @(x)find_root(x,e);
z = fzero(fun,1);
yy = z+.5^2*z/e-z^3/e;

%% Functions
function y = find_root(x,e)
    y1 = x+0.5^2*x/e-x^3/e;
    y = -e*x + e*y1 +.5^2*y1-y1^3;
end
```

Good luck with your future MATLAB endeavours and don't ever feel silly for mistakes like this, we have all made them at some point!